# how to snap one fixed header to another using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have been working on a some jquery to create a fixed nav (yellow block ) that that snaps into place (red block) when scrolled.

1)The issue  I was having is that the snap became jumpy and wouldnt display all the imagery clean. It would jump half way down the page.

2) It would not work across browsers, only chrome... please help?

here is my working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/18/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
#profile-container {
    padding-top:52px;
    /* Red bar height */
    margin:0;
    /* Clear default browser margin */
}
#profile-container.fixed {
    padding-top:82px;
    /* Red bar height + yellow bar height */
}
#profile-container {
    height:2000px;
}
#fixed-header {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    top:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
.container {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.sticky-header {
    width:700px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
}
.sticky-header {
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
.fixed .sticky-header {
    position: fixed;
    top:52px;
    margin-bottom:52px;
}
.img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    float:left;
}
</style>
<script>
var offset = $(".sticky-header").offset();
var sticky = document.getElementById("sticky-header")
var additionalPixels = 50;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
        $('#profile-container').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#profile-container').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
</script>
<body>

<div id="profile-container">
    <div id="fixed-header"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="sticky-header">This needs to be fixed when hits top of screen</div>
    <div class="img">needs to be smooth</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question. Or give feedback if it did not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You make a mistake while getting `scrollTop()`.

What do you scroll ? browser window isn't it ?

So try this :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top - additionalPixels) {
    //your stuffs here
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gacp/)**

For other browsers, it seems this is jQuery which is falty. With jQuery-1.10, $(window).scroll() doesn't work in IE (tested with IE10). With jQuery-1.9, it works !

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/47rYp/)** with jquery-1.9.

Comment: Good explanation on why it was not working.  I didn't know why the scrollTop value in his original example was always 0.

Comment: I cant seem to get this working in my own document. if i use the jquery reference, should this be ok? <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Are you starting your project, or is it already fully devlopped ? Why not trying to replace your js call with this one, being careful that what you already did still work :http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make some changes the `280` is just a rough number but this example should help.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 280){
      $('.sticky-header').css('top','52px');
      $('.sticky-header').css('position','fixed');
}
else{
    $('.sticky-header').css('top','auto');
    $('.sticky-header').css('position','static');    
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f95sW/22/

Comment: @Paul Designer please mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question. Or give feedback if it did not.  Thanks